# How to display unlimited items horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items in one of my view.
I can only fit up to 6 items, and it's laid out like this:

[image]

I used `class="col-md-2"` for each one.

---

When I have more than 6, it just simply go down to the another row.
I don’t want that. You can see it here.

[image]

---

Now, `if` the list has `6` `or` `more` items,

- list them horizontally
- show the big `>` so that the users will know that there is more
- show the 2 dots in the middle

[image]

`Edit`
This is what I got so far. I used Larval 4 so this syntax is in `HTML/Blade`.

```
@foreach ( MarketingMaterialCategory::all() as $mmc )

    <h2><i class="fa fa-file-image-o color lighter"></i>&nbsp; {{{ $mmc->name or '' }}} &nbsp;<small> </small></h2>

    <div class="row">

    @foreach ( MarketingMaterial::where('marketing_materials_category_id','=', $mmc->id )->get() as $marketing_material)

    <div class="col-md-2" >
        <!-- Shopping items -->
        <div class="shopping-item">
            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 imgbox" >
                <!-- <span class="col-sm-6"></span> -->
                <a href="#"><img class="col-sm-12 pull-right" width="200" src="/marketing_materials/{{$marketing_material->id}}/download/thumb_path" alt="" /></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Shopping item name / Heading -->
            <h6><a href="#">{{{ $marketing_material->title or '' }}}</a><span class="color pull-right">{{ FileHelper::formatBytes($marketing_material->media_size,0) }}</span></h6>

            <!-- Shopping item hover block & link -->
            <div class="item-hover bg-color hidden-xs">
                <a href="#">Download</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach

    </div>
    <hr>

@endforeach
```

Can someone help me how to resolve this ?

Comment: what have you done so far ?? Please post some of your code.. ^^

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Surely there must be some sort of library out there to achieve this, by the way.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't support that kind of scrolling. However, I have used this JavaScript library in the past and it does pretty much exactly what you want: [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

It is very flexible and it will only show the scrolling options if it can't display all the contents on the page.

If you use it though, do not use the bootstrap col-md-2 classes, just set a manual width.

Comment: This works especially well if your minimum number of items already takes up the width of their container. +1